# Accessing devices data from Facebook graph Api request in swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I have made a graph request using the FBSDK in my swift application for iphone and I am having some difficulty accessing some of the information it has returned in the result. Specifically I want to get the list of device platforms the user uses. Playing around with the Graph api explorer I get this data for a query on a user's devices.

```
{
  "devices": [
    {
      "os": "iOS"
    }
  ], 
  "id": "12345678912345"
}
```

but in swift the data returned is in this format when I print the graph results value to console:

```
{
    devices =     (
                    {
                os = iOS;
            }
        );
}
```

so my question is, how do I get the value of 'os' in swift? all my attempts casting the data to NSDictionaries and NSArrays etc have all failed.

```
let listOfDevices: String = result.valueForKey("devices") as? String
```

outputs

```
devices =     (
                        {
                    os = iOS;
                }
            );
```

which just goes to show it doesn't contain any key/pair values for an NSDictionary when I search for ["os"] because of those"()" parenthesis. All help appreciated. Probably something really simple...

I don't want to use string regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listOfDevices` should be a dictionary.

**Swift 2**

```
do {
    // Replicating your data for the example
    let response = "{\"devices\": [{\"os\": \"iOS\"}],\"id\": \"12345678912345\"}"
    // Cast the response as a Dictionary with String as key and AnyObject as value
    if let data = response.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
        listOfDevices = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] {
        // Value of `devices` is an array of dictionaries
        if let devices = listOfDevices["devices"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
            for device in devices {
                if let os = device["os"] as? String {
                    print(os)
                }
            }
        }
        // Value of `id` is a String
        if let id = listOfDevices["id"] as? String {
            // use `id`
        }
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

**Swift 1**

```
// Replicating your data for the example
let response = "{\"devices\": [{\"os\": \"iOS\"}],\"id\": \"12345678912345\"}"
let data = response.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

// Cast the response as a Dictionary with String as key and AnyObject as value
let listOfDevices = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! [String:AnyObject]

// Value of `devices` is an array of dictionaries
if let devices = listOfDevices["devices"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    for device in devices {
        if let os = device["os"] as? String {
            println(os)
        }
    }
}

// Value of `id` is a String
if let id = listOfDevices["id"] as? String {
    // use `id`
}
```